# In how many ways we can divide 10 apples among 3 people in such a way that each should get at least 2 apples?

Tags: combinatorics

i also want to know how to think of this type of problems if it was at least one apple or two or three what's the logic behind it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: There have been tons of discussion about this kind of problem here. Next time you're posting a question, please look for older discussions on similar problems. Hint: this is the same as distributing 4 apples to 3 people (because you anyway have to give two to each in the beginning, so $10-2\times 3 = 4$)

Comment: i read them actually and i read the at least one also but none have at least two i searched them

Comment: Whether the lower limit is 1 or 2, doesn't change the way that you solve the problem. Only the actual numbers that you plug in.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/In-how-many-ways-we-can-divide-10-apples-among-3-people-in-such-a-way-that-each-should-get-atleast-1-apple teh method descriped here using linear algebra didn't do any thing with the at least one it only stated that how we choose number of pluses in the equation from the over all number of pluses in the original equation not after the subtratctoin

Comment: It might seem expeditious to pose the problem to be solved entirely in the title, and use the body of the Question only for "editorial" content, but this is discouraged.  Please edit the post to make a self-contained problem statement in the body of the Question and add some context (e.g. why are these problems important to you and/or what specific difficulty did you find with your own approach?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption**. Apples are identical but people are not.

1. Due to the assumption that apples are indistinguishable, we can give each person 2 apples so that we have $10-3\times2=4$ apples left. Therefore, the problem is reduced to counting the number of ways to distribute 4 apples among 3 people.
2. The number of ways to distribute 4 apples among 3 people is $\binom{4+3-1}{3-1}=15.$ The argument used to establish this is often referred to as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Examples), which says that there are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to place $n$ identical stars into $k$ non-identical bins. In our case, the stars are the $n=4$ apples and the bins are the $k=3$ people.

Comment: thanks a lot that what i was looking for .

Comment: Your second calculation (non-identical apples) is incorrect. If the first person gets apple #1 and then apple #2, then it should be considered the same as if he gets #2 and then #1. It is only the final distribution of apples that matters, not the order in which they are received. Your method counts those as distinct ways.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Woops. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Your revised method is still incorrect. It still distinguishes the first two apples from the rest. So while it considers #1,#2,#3 and #2,#1,#3 the same now, these are still considered different to #3,#1,#2 or #2,#3,#1 for example, when they should be the same.

Comment: I will embarrassingly delete that part of the post and maybe fix it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

1)let's say the apples are identical 
W1 + 2 + w2 +2 + w3 +2 = 10 (w is whole no.) And wi represents no of apple ith person gets
W1 + w2 + w3 = 4 implying 6c2 ways(beggar's method)

2) they are not identical
10= 2+2+6 or 2+3+5 or 2+ 4 +4 or 3+3+4. 
We will make groups and arrange
10!/(2!2!6!2!)×3!(extra division of 2! Because there are 2 groups, If u know this then good but if u don't let me know I will explain)+10!(2!3!5!)*3!+10!/(2!4!4!2!)*3!+10!(3!3!4!2!)*3!